How to move the color blocks into the red frame region marked?
I'd like to use the area below the two first subfigures to place the color blocks, how can I achieve this effect?

The mwe is following
\documentclass[aspectratio=2013]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Phase Diagram}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Sk.Tube to Toron}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Sk.Tube to Bobber}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Different vertical anisotropy constants $K$ of the top and bottom layers with fixed extra fields}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
            \filldraw [fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle+ (4,2) node [below,black] at (2,0) {Uniform};
            \filldraw [fill=red] (5,0) rectangle+ (4,2) node [below,black] at (7,0) {Sk.Tube};
            \filldraw [fill=green] (10,0) rectangle+ (4,2) node [below,black] at (12,0) {Toron};
            \filldraw [fill=blue] (15,0) rectangle+ (4,2) node [below,black] at (17,0) {Bobber};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

(What's more, I think use tikz to arrange the three subfigures directly is not a good way)

You can take advantage of the node names and the remember picture option, that way in a tikz picture environment with the overlay option you can draw whatever using points relative to the node name coordinates in each tikzpicture that you defined in the previous environments that you indicated to remember, so you can position exactly what you want and go from one to another with arrows or whatever.
In this case each image is inside a node in a tikzpicture environment with the option remember picture, each node has a name like IMG-1, that way you can reach those points later using IMG-1.center, IMG-1.north, etc. then shift those points using the calc library that allows you to add shifts to these points $(node_name)+(x_shift,y_shift)$; I recommend working in em, since it is relative to the font size.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[aspectratio=2013]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Phase Diagram}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
                    \draw(0,0) node[inner sep=0](IMG-1){\includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{Sk.Tube to Toron}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
                    \draw(0,0) node[inner sep=0](IMG-2){\includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{Sk.Tube to Bobber}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
                    \draw(0,0) node[inner sep=0](IMG-3){\includegraphics[height=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{Different vertical anisotropy constants $K$ of the top and bottom layers with fixed extra fields}
            \end{subfigure} 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \def\HdistImgA{2em}%vertical distance from ImageA
                \filldraw [fill=gray] ($(IMG-1.south west)+(-0.5em,-\HdistImgA)$) |- ($(IMG-1.south)+(-0.5em,-\HdistImgA-2em)$) node[pos=0.75,anchor=90,black]{\small Uniform} |- cycle;
                \filldraw [fill=red] ($(IMG-1.south)+(0.5em,-\HdistImgA)$) |- ($(IMG-1.south east)+(0.5em,-\HdistImgA-2em)$) node[pos=0.75,anchor=90,black]{\small Sk.Tube} |- cycle;
                \filldraw [fill=green] ($(IMG-2.south west)+(-0.5em,-\HdistImgA)$) |- ($(IMG-2.south)+(-0.5em,-\HdistImgA-2em)$) node[pos=0.75,anchor=90,black]{\small Toron} |- cycle;
                \filldraw [fill=blue] ($(IMG-2.south)+(0.5em,-\HdistImgA)$) |- ($(IMG-2.south east)+(0.5em,-\HdistImgA-2em)$) node[pos=0.75,anchor=90,black]{\small Bobber} |- cycle;
                \draw[->,thick](IMG-3.north) |- ++(0,2em)  -| (IMG-2.north) node[pos=0.25,anchor=-90]{\small some relation};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}


Made entirely with TikZ, even though it doesn't suit you.
\documentclass[aspectratio=2013]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{legend/.style={fill=#1,minimum width=1.6cm,minimum height=.8cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Phase Diagram}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Images and captions
\node[label=below:Sk.Tube to Toron] (Sk1) {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
           
\node[right=5mm of Sk1,label=below:Sk1.Tube to Bobber] (Sk2) {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}};

\node[right=5mm of Sk2] (Sk3) {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
\node[below=0pt of Sk3,text width=4cm,anchor=north]{Different vertical anisotropy constants $K$ of the top and bottom layers with fixed extra fields};

% legends
\node[below right= 5mm and 0 cm of Sk1.south west,legend=gray,label=below:Uniform] (Leg1){};
\node[right= 5mm of Leg1,legend=red,label=below:Sk.Tube] (Leg2){};
\node[right= 5mm of Leg2,legend=green,label=below:Toron] (Leg3){};
\node[right= 5mm of Leg3,legend=blue,label=below:Bobber] (Leg4){};
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


